# Is there a way to enable SVG support in Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, svg, flex4

I am using Adobe AIR to create a desktop application. The AIR app is very simple, it consists of a tabs that each contain a HTML component (AIR HTML Control). The HTML component is simply passed a URL (location) and renders it.

My problem is that one of the locations is a page that contains SVG. An example location is [here](http://www.december.com/html/demo/hellosvg.html)

the AIR HTML component does not (appear to) render SVG :( Is there a way to enable SVG in AIR or a workaround for it ?

Thanks in advance.
Jon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're out of luck according to this [article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/articles/air_and_webkit.html).