# SVG support in Adobe AIR 16.0

Tags: html, svg, air, adobe, amcharts

I'm trying to use the [AMCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/) library in a HTML5 Adobe AIR app. Unfortunately this library relies on SVG and according to [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-67c0013e126afbe6c4d-8000.html) SVG is a Webkit feature not supported in AIR. I have tested this with the most recent version of AIR 16.0.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this, or perhaps a 3rd party plugin that enables SVG support in AIR? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988234/is-there-a-way-to-enable-svg-support-in-adobe-air) was asked over 2 years ago on SO, but with SVG increasing in popularity is Adobe planning to introduce SVG support in future versions of AIR?

Comment: Hi @Ben - were you ever able to find any information on this?

Comment: @ScottCate sadly not, I abandoned AIR in the end and instead went with [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron)